# wso2 5.3 org.wso2.carbon.utils.Secret git repo

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am on wso2 5.3, could you please share the git repository for the following class:

```
org.wso2.carbon.utils.Secret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using wso2is-5.3.0 and it is based on carbon-kernel 4.4.11 [[1]](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/). You can find the Secret class in carbon-kernel [[2]](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.11/core/org.wso2.carbon.utils/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/utils/Secret.java).

Comment: Thanks, i got it.